# How to check if element is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` which represents a `navbar` on the page. Before it are other elements like logos, banners and etc... 
I want to do `navbar` sticky only when it's is scrolled down, i.e. when i scroll down and left it behind i need to add class to it. How can i catch this moment?

There should be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
// if jQuery('#navbar') is already scrolled down add to it .navbar-fixed else remove        
});
```

Comment: You may need to clarify your question, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: you need to calculate the initial offsets position of the element...and the final offset position of the element..just get the difference between both,..that will give you the scroll

Comment: @VAGABOND so i'm asking how to do that?

Comment: Try building a jsFiddle with the code you've tried so far... Then ask a specific question about the piece of code that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the scrollbar with [`jQueryElement.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). You can get the offset from the 'navbar' with [`jQueryElement.offset().top`.](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). You can use this to calculate if the user scrolled past the navbar:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if( $(document).scrollTop() > $('#navbar').offset().top ) {
    $('#navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
  } else {
    $('#navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
  }
});
```